# Deselect default selection on selecting any other option bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using Bootstrap-select plugin (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for my dropdown multiple select box.

I have enabled a default option which is ticked when the page load. Image below

[image]

```html
<select id="dataPicker" class="selectpicker" multiple>
 <optgroup  >
  <option value="default" selected="selected">ALL</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup ">
  <option value="failed">FAILED</option>
  <option value="running">RUNNING</option>
  <option value="completed">COMPLETED</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

In the above code "ALL" will be selected by default .

I am looking for a behavior that when a user selects any option other than "ALL" then "ALL" automatically gets deselected .

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Add 'data-actions-box="true"' to your select element.

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true">
      <option>Mustard</option>
      <option>Ketchup</option>
      <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#selectdeselect-all-options

If you would like to continue via your method then you will need to add a event hook on the select item event and check to see if the item is the 'All' item and manually deselect all items in the list and vice versa.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerselectall

Answer (score 0):

If this can helps someone yet, the answer could be with jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '#dataPicker', function (e)
{
var select = $(this)[0];

if (select[0].selected) {

    $("#dataPicker").val([]).val('default').selectpicker("refresh");

}
});
```